# What does "washing all traces of the snow away *in clear, icy ribbons down* the side of the walkway" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> I didn't really want to walk to class with Mike as usual — he seemed to be a
> popular target for the snowball snipers — but when we went to the door,
> everyone besides me groaned in unison. It was raining, washing all traces of the
> snow away **in clear, icy ribbons down the side of the walkway.** I pulled my hood
> up, secretly pleased. I would be free to go straight home after Gym.

I kind of get what the part marked in stars means, but don't understand exactly what it means.

So does "in" here indicate the way/fashion/manner the rain melted snow away? And what about the "ribbons"? is it also what the scene looked like when the rain swept away some of the snow? and what's the function of "down"?

As you can tell, I'm totally lost with this sentence and I'd really appreciate it if you could help me with it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The rain is melting the snow and the other kids won't be able to make snowballs. A walkway is often slightly cambered so that water will drain off it. If the walkway is contained by, say, grassy edges then you get a small stream running away along each side (like ribbons of water). You must have seen this.

Comment: Yes,  "in" here ***does*** indicate the way/fashion/manner the rain melted snow away. In principle you could switch the preposition to ***as***. But for reasons I can't put my finger on, making that apparently trivial change seems to very strongly encourage the addition of an extra verb: *washing the snow away **as** clear, icy ribbons **running**  down the side of the walkway.*  Note that the word ***running*** could be added to the ***in*** version as well, but it doesn't seem so "necessary" there.